# BigQuery InternalError loading from Cloud Storage (works with direct file upload)

Tags: google-bigquery

Whenever I try to load a CSV file stored in CloudStorage into BigQuery, I get an InternalError (both using the web interface as well as the command line). The CSV is (an abbreviated) part of the Google Ngram dataset.

command like:

```
bq load 1grams.ngrams gs://otichybucket/import_test.csv word:STRING,year:INTEGER,freq:INTEGER,volume:INTEGER
```

gives me:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'otichyproject1:bqjob_r28187461b449065a_000001504e747a35_1': An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
```

However, when I load this file directly using the web interface and the File upload as a source (loading from my local drive), it works.

I need to load from Cloud Storage, since I need to load much larger files (original ngrams datasets).

I tried different files, always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an engineer on the BigQuery team. I was able to look up your job, and it looks like there was a problem reading the Google Cloud Storage object.

Unfortunately, we didn't log much of the context, but looking at the code, the things that could cause this are:

1. The URI you specified for the job is somehow malformed. It doesn't look malformed, but maybe there is some odd UTF8 non-printing character that I didn't notice.
2. The 'region' for your bucket is somehow unexpected. Is there any chance you've set data location on your GCS bucket to something other than {US, EU, or ASIA}. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations) for more info on bucket locations. If so, and you've set location to a region, rather than a continent, that could cause this error.
3. There could have been some internal error in GCS that caused this. However, I didn't see this in any of the logs, and it should be fairly rare.

We're putting in some more logging to detect this in the future and to fix the issue with regional buckets (however, regional buckets may fail, because bigquery doesn't support cross-region data movement, but at least they will fail with an intelligible error).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 
I think 1 should not apply, since I copied everything directly from Chrome.

2. you are right, the bucket was in a region, I'll try again with a US bucket and report back.

It would certainly help if the errors were a bit more intelligible. After failing with uploaded ngram data, I attempted to work with the public trigram dataset and failed miserably, with

otichyproject1:job_5C7IPqdwS_owrMRIvqzodO8Q7NI

running for 2,5 hours and ending with yet another internal error. Should I start a new question for that?

Comment: OK, you were right, loading to BigQuery from a bucket in the same continent worked ok, thanks!